# Is there a way to make a view run without having to show the view in the browser in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, view, chart.js

I explain, I have a Laravel project where i need to make a report and display it in the browser for download. That report need to have some graphs made by Chartjs and this is what I have done.

my routes:

```
Route::get('/informe', 'informeController@procesar');
Route::get('/graph', 'informeController@graph');
Route::post('/save', 'informeController@graphStore');
Route::get('/up', 'informeController@graphUpdate');
```

a really big controller, but who has this pseudocode.

```
public function graph()
{
    return view('graphMaker');
}
public function graphUpdate(Request $request)
{
    //get data from a database and send it to a view that requested data
    return response()->json($data);
}

public function graphStore(Request $request){
    //save the images obtained from the view using this commands in JS
    //ctx2 = document.getElementById('donutchart');
    //img = ctx2.toDataURL('image/png');

    return route('/informe');
}

public function procesar(){
    //get more data from the database and generate a pdf using mpdf
}
```

Finally, the view just make 2 charts in HTML using Chartjs and a JS code that updates the charts with the required information. This is a blade view.

So my question is if there is a method to generate the charts using the view and downdload as png but without it being seen in the browser, all through laravel.

And after all that, how to display the pdf in the bowser? Because when making queries it doesn't show me the `procesar()` output(`$ mpdf-> Output ();`).

If I forgot to mention something or information is needed just ask me. Thank you all.

Comment: if you already saved your pdf to the file system, you can do: `return response()->download($pathToFile)` [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#file-downloads). if not, check out streamed downloads on the same page.

Comment: I tried and it didn't work. the ```$pathtofile``` must to be complete path or can be a relative path?

Answer (score 0):

I get what you are asking, you can get the compiled blade template ie: in HTML format using the `render()` method like the following.

`$html = view('graphMaker')->render()`

But the problem is that the chart you are trying to make is done using `chart.js` which is a clientside library. Which means you need a browser to draw the actual chart.

One option is to render the chart from server-side (ie: in PHP itself) using a library (Which you will have to find yourself but one link is [here](https://www.codediesel.com/php/6-excellent-charting-libraries-for-php/)) and pass the rendered html to `Mpdf` for making the pdf, But the fact is there are no good charting options in the server-side.

**The best bet I think is to use the [chrome driver](https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver) to load the HTML and take a screenshot (If I am not wrong you can directly make PDF from it)**

Comment: Oh thanks! it's just what i wanted. Anyway thank you very much